# Python - Use a data coming from a choices function

Tags: python

I need some help. I have the following code:

```
clients = {'A': '300', 'B': '100', 'C': '500', 'D': '250', 'E': '150'}
Elem = list(clients.keys())
Val = list(clients.values())
interElem = list(map(int, Val))
W = sum(interElem)
TW = [i/W for i in interElem]
Country = (choices(Elem, W))
```

I need exactly that the choice above that it's going to be

```
['A'], ['B'], ['C'].....['E']
```

going into the following code. `x` is the value defined in the dictionary clients for the country selected above

```
x = clients['Country'] 
num = random.randint(0,x)
cadena = str(num)
num_cadena = cadena.rjust(4,"0")
print(num_cadena)
```

Comment: What do you want help with?

Comment: This code doesn't work. I need that the variable x take the value from the dictionary as of the key gives by the variable Country. I can make for example a function with the first part of the code I posted that return Country, and the call the function, but I don't know either how to search into the diccionary from the value given by this function

Answer (score 0):

`Country` is a list containing a single element.
that element is a key that you can use to search the users dictionary.

to access an item by index in a list use list[index]
to access a value by key in a dictionary use dict[key]

```
>>> clients = {'A': '300', 'B': '100', 'C': '500', 'D': '250', 'E': '150'}
>>> ...
>>> Country = (choices(Elem, W))
>>> Country
['A']
>>> Country[0]
'A'
>>> clients[Country[0]]
'300'
```

Comment: @CristinaDominguezFernandez i cant see your code but i assume your getting a TypeError from random.randint, if that is the case you should use `int(x)` instead of `x`